# Edge DevTools crashing when attaching debugger

Tags: office-js, exceljs

I am trying to make use of the new DevTools for Edge Chromium for my Excel Desktop Addin (Yeoman scaffolding with React and Typescript.
I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-desktop-using-edge-chromium)
but some very strange occurance happens here. If I click on attach debugger, I get to see the DevTools for about 5 seconds and than it crashes the addin.
"ADD-IN ERROR, this add-in seems to be having problems. click "restart" to try starting it again.
The addin restarts but I cannot debug my addin at all. My Windows is 20H2 and Excel is running the lastest version: 2104.
What can I do to prevent the 5 seconds crashes? I already did an NPM install to make sure that all packages were updated using:

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

but to no avail.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I suggest that you raise an issue on the [office-js repo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=).

Comment: This also happens in PowerPoint and Excel desktop apps for me as well. I can only debug the Online Apps